# All Azure WebJob possible statuses

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I would like to know all possible statuses for a triggered WebJob. I need this because of possible scenarios that might occur if something unwanted happenes.

I found this answer: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32612 by BryanTrach-MSFT but I find that answer insufficient. Maybe because he forgot some statuses like Failed or Success or because he was talking about Continuous WebJobs.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Get Triggered Web Job api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/gettriggeredwebjob), there're 3 [TriggeredWebJobStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/gettriggeredwebjob#triggeredwebjobstatus): `Error`, `Failed`, `Success`. A screenshot as below:

[image]

By the way, the [status for continuous webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getcontinuouswebjob#continuouswebjobstatus) are as below:

[image]